# How to append variable content inside div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have some content stored inside a variable and i want to append that content String inside a html div.

This is the script code:

```
 if ( $( "#eroare" ).val()!="") {
    alert("Error 2" + $( "#eroare" ).val());
    var aux = $( "#eroare" ).val();
    alert("aux="+aux);
    $( "#errorSuccess" ).html( "<b>" + aux + "</b>"); //this is not working
}
```

And this is the html:

```
<div id="errorSuccess" >ceva</div>
<div><input type="hidden" id="eroare" value="${sessionScope.errmsg}" /></div>
```

Comment: `$( "#errorSuccess" ).append( "<b>" + aux + "</b>");` ???

Comment: `//this is not working` which means???

Comment: that line is not working

Comment: What do you mean with `it's not working?` Your code should change the content of `errorSuccess` unless the if condition is not met

Comment: Saying it doesn't work without saying **why** is useless. What *is* it doing? What *should* it being doing instead?

Comment: .... i ask for some help and you all downvote me, for nothing. That line should add the code inside the div with id=errorSuccess, and it doesn't

Comment: I have tested this and working fine with chrome browser. Check properly, before getting alert popup you should see 'ceva' and after closing alert popup it is updating with hidden value. Check if you are getting input hidden value or not.

Comment: @RazvanN it will work, there must be other problem.  Check console.  See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/62cJc/

Comment: I know it should, but i get the alerts ok, with those values..after that, it doesn't append that String there...

Comment: @Razvan You should check what the `${sessionScope.errmsg}` variable returns! Maybe it doesn't return something, so it will skip the `if` check(because it's empty)

Comment: @n1kkou it is not empty, the alert is showing the value

Comment: @RazvanN test this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AH8vv/ . Is that what you want?

Comment: @n1kkou yes, that's what i want, thanks, but it doesn't work for me, probably because i am loading the page in an iframe, and the div is outside that. the only way i managed to do that is with this: $("input[name='eroare']"), and not inside a div, but in an input text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i was using an iframe to load page content for an upload form, i had to load the page again with a redirect from my servlet in order to get the parameters i needed from the session.

After that, the only solution i found was this:

```
var aux = $( "#eroare" ).val();
$("input[name='errorSuccess2']").val(aux);
```

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Next time, please take care to provide details on why you think it does not work, example : alerts prints "something" while `#errorSuccess` remains empty.

Answer (score 10):

```
$("#errorSuccess").append("<b>" + aux + "</b>");
```

or, if you want to be at the beginning of the `#errorSuccess` content, you need to replace `append` with `prepend`

Answer (score 1):

Use `append` instead of `html`

```
$("#errorSuccess").append( "<b>" + aux + "</b>");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvSJL/)